# Does the N-dimensional hypervolume refer to the N attributes we have in the training sets?

Tags: clustering, data-visualization, feature-selection, categorical-encoding, dbscan

If we have $N$ features in the feature set that is being used to train a machine learning model, does the $N$ here cause the data points to be in hyperspace provided that $N > 3$? I'm assuming that space beyond 3D is termed hyperspace(?).

Details: I recently trained `DBSCAN` clustering model on a simple dataset that contained 2 attributes. The attributes were categorical and so I used One Hot encoding for both features. This resulted in several columns/features being created (I used Pandas' `get_dummies()` function). While trying to *plot* the result and visualize, I noticed that most simple examples I found on the Internet refer to 2D points created on the $X,Y$ axis. For example, these would generate a blob of random 2D points and plot those ([see here](https://ogrisel.github.io/scikit-learn.org/sklearn-tutorial/auto_examples/cluster/plot_dbscan.html)) easily on a 2D plot. But how do I plot when my dummy feature set after One Hot encoding has *several* attributes (> 8) and is therefore in hyperspace?

- Am I understanding correct that after One Hot encoding, my feature set went in N-dimensional hyperspace and therefore cannot be plotted?
- Am I correct in assuming that if we *were* to plot this N-dimensional set, we'd have to use dimensionality reduction concepts to reduce the features and bring the feature set in 3D/2D space?
- How is `X[:,0], X[:,1]` able to capture N-feature sets (where $N > 3$) in these plotting examples:

  ```
  X = ss.fit_transform(X)
  db = DBSCAN(eps=eps, min_samples=min_samples)
  db.fit(X)
  y_pred = db.fit_predict(X)
  plt.scatter(X[:,0], X[:,1],c=y_pred, cmap='Paired')
  ```

Context: My work is related more to data security and I'm new to data science. While I find the field very intriguing and have been having some success testing out practical use of popular ML models, I am struggling to wrap my head around some meta concepts and formulating a picture in my head. I do not have access to formal classes/professor so I'm sorry if this is a basic question. It is also a question which I can't easily Google (not sure how to formulate the Google search)